# Copy from individual cell in Google Sheets Table Chart

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-charts, google-chart-api

I'm using appscript to build and insert a table chart into a sheet when a button has been pushed.

```
var chart = sheet.newChart()
.setChartType(Charts.ChartType.TABLE)
.addRange(outrange2)
.setPosition(2, 12, 35, -5)
.setOption('height', 445)
.setNumHeaders(1)
.setOption('page', 'enable')
.build();
sheet.insertChart(chart);
```

The chart gets created and inserted properly though my users are unable to interact with the contents of this table directly, they can only scroll and change pages.

I have checked to see if there were any required options that need to be enabled when before building the chart, the appscript guide references me to this page when advising on options:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table

In the reference table and the overview above it states that "Users can select single rows either with the keyboard or the mouse. Users can sort rows by clicking on column headers. The header row remains fixed as the user scrolls. The table fires a number of events corresponding to user interaction"

The table that appears in my sheet is not like the one that appears in the reference and I am unable to copy text from the cells or select individual rows in the newly generated table. When attempting to interact with this table from google sheets it seemingly only allows us to resize and scroll up and down the table.

Are there ways to get around this or some attributes that I am missing to allow us to interact with individual entries from the table chart?

[image: Table]

[image: Data]

Comment: Welcome. Would you edit your question to include a screenshot of your completed chart, and also a screenshot (or text table) of the data represented by `outrange2`.

Comment: Hey Tedinoz, I've added the requested screenshots to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yours code creates a embedded chart using Google AppsScript.  [Class EmbeddedTableChartBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-table-chart-builder) links to the Gviz documentation, and it says "Users can select single rows either with the keyboard or the mouse."

However I don't think that it is intended that an embedded sheet should be scrapable since Google Charts are HTML based. Consider lodging an issue to clarify expectations.